# How can I run a powershell script in another *.ps1

Tags: powershell

Assuming that I have established previously in the code the get-game function
and have already created C:\Stock_Market\$Username.ps1 and this file is in the same C:\Stock_Market folder why can the system not find $Username.ps1?

And how can I call the commands from $Username.ps1 to run in this file?

```
function Log-In {
    Clear-Host

    $Username = Read-Host "Username"
    $Password = Read-Host "Password"
    $filepath = "C:\Stock_Market\$Username.ps1"

    If (Test-Path $filepath) {
        ./$Username.ps1
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host "$Username does not exist"
    }

    # Logging in

    if ($Password -eq $realpass) {
        get-game
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host "Wrong Password!"
        pause
        Clear-Host
        Log-In
    }
}
```

Comment: Invoke it in-place `. ./$Username.ps1` or in its own scope `& ./$Username.ps1` I guess.

Comment: Because you're not running the script from the c:\stock_market folder so `.\ ` refers to the wrong place?

Comment: Thank you, that ampersand made a big difference!

Comment: Just design one script with the functions you need. `$something = Function-InScript` then you can work with `$something` later in the script.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to use the ampersand in front of the script name, this calls the string as a command and not as a cmdlet or a string.

It's known as the call operator.

Refer to [SS64 Call Operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) for more info and syntax.